# How to make a SUM without group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, window-functions

Here is my problem..

```
Actual   Auction   Ammanat   id
7000     500       100       228,229
7000     100       100       228,229
7000     900       100       228,229
5000     0         0         230
```

I want result as given below

```
Actual   Auction   Ammanat   Remaining  id
7000     500       100       5550       228,229
7000     100       100       5550       228,229
7000     900       100       5550       228,229
5000     0         0         5000        230
```

Here, `Remaining` is `(sum(auction)-actual)`.

I am using PostgreSQL. But if anyone know solution in SQL Server, it will be OK.

Comment: `(sum(auction)-actual)` doesn't make sense. Should probably be `actual - sum(auction)`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need a to use a window function - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-window.html

Something like:

```
(Sum(Auction) OVER ()) - actual AS Remaining
```

Comment: Thank you so much... i want ask also that, how to deal with this problem in SQL?

Comment: SQL Server also has this feature, with the same syntax: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: I think it should be `actual - Sum(Auction) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS Remaining`

Comment: Hello! If I execute: 

SELECT  sum(x) 
FROM data

The result is: "ERROR: column "x" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"... 

Instead if y execute:

SELECT  sum(x)  as my_label
FROM data

Works fine.... :S I am using postgresql...

Does the SOLUTION is add an alias???

Comment: @Gabriel - this is not really related to the original question - OP asked about using an aggregate together with a individual rows, while you are asking about a general error you get trying to using a simple aggregate. This deserves its own question (or maybe even a ticket in the PostgreSQL issue tracker, since it does look like a bug...)

Comment: AWSOME! I have looked up tons of pages and this is the proper answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

Idan is 100% correct. I want to provide an explanation of this:

```
(SUM (Auction) OVER ())
```

- `OVER ()` creates a *window* including *all rows* from the original query.
- `SUM (Auction)` is a *window function* that calculates the sum of `Auction`.

Here is further explanation:

- **Window** is a user-specified set of rows within a query result set.
- **Window Function** computes a value (e.g. `SUM`) over all rows in the window.
- **All rows** are in the window because `OVER()` does not include `PARTITION BY`. With `PARTITION BY` the window would include a subset of rows.

[From MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

> ...the OVER clause defines a window or user-specified set of rows within a query result set. A window function then computes a value for each row in the window. You can use the OVER clause with functions to compute aggregated values... if the OVER clause does not include PARTITION BY. This means that the function will be applied to all rows returned by the query.

Comment: Thank you for this.