# Getting SUM of elements without GroupBy

Tags: sql

Here is my table

```
a  |  b  |  c
1     2     3
1     2     3
1     2     3
```

Is it possible to write `select`, which will return me something like this:

```
select * from table1 where a = 1

a  |  b  |  c
1     2     9
```

In the last column I want to get `SUM` of all elements in column `c`

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Please explain the logic you require for all columns.  Is `b` going to be the `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `AVG()`, something else?  Also, ***why*** does this need to avoid `GROUP BY`?  This is all very vague...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271646/how-to-make-a-sum-without-group-by (SUM (Auction) OVER ())

Comment: @Brandon_R Thank you, this is exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

Where does the a and b come from in your results? What if there's a row (42, 7, 12)? Group by allows you to *group* the results based on other columns, which can then be included in the results as the group "keys". If you don't group, you can only use aggregate functions in the results.

If all you want is to get the sum of c, why not just `select sum(c) from table1 where a = 1;`. You can't select a or b, since there can be multiple different values for a and b.